# В оконном режиме браузера "ломается" навёрстанный сайт

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, веб-программирование

Учусь веб-разработке, только начал всем этим заниматься, тренируюсь верстая найденные psd-макеты. Столкнулся с тем, что когда я сворачиваю браузер в оконный режим, то сайт начинает "ломаться": текст наползает друг на друга. Сетку делаю с помощью флекс-контейнеров. Приложу скрины (первый в полноэкранном и второй в оконном режиме). Почему такое может происходить?[image: полноэкранный режим][image: Оконный режим]

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не пробовали делать адаптив? Да и вы походу для блоков с текстом, прописываете height...

http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media